# Retornando dados do input sem usar form Django

Tags: html, python, django, post, forms

Ola pessoal gostaria de tirar uma duvida fiz um campos request post aqui para cadastrar um usuario e tambem ja usando um foreing key para cadastrar alguns outros dados dele como cpf e celular.
porem como nao estou usando um form gosraria de saber como faço para quandouma validação que retorna ele novamente para o cadastro os dados estarem preenchidos.

```
usuario.view

def cadastro(request):
    """Cadastra uma nova pessoa no sistema """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nome = request.POST['nome']
        email = request.POST['email']
        senha = request.POST['password']
        senha2 = request.POST['password2']
        cpf = request.POST['cpf']
        celular = request.POST['celular']       

        

        if campo_vazio(nome):
            messages.error(request, 'O campo nome não pode ficar em branco')
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if not validacpf(cpf):
            messages.error(request, 'CPF invalido', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if campo_vazio(email):
            messages.error(request, 'O campo email não pode ficar em branco', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if campo_vazio(cpf):
            messages.error(request, 'O campo CPF não pode ficar em branco', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if campo_vazio(celular):
            messages.error(request, 'O campo celular não pode ficar em branco', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if senhas_nao_sao_iguais(senha, senha2):
            messages.error(request, 'As senhas não são iguais', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'Usuário já cadastrado', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if Usuario.objects.filter(cpf=cpf).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'CPF ja cadastrado', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        if User.objects.filter(username=nome).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'Usuário já cadastrado', "danger")
            return redirect('cadastro')
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=nome,
            email=email,
            password=senha)

    

id_usuario = User.objects.get(username=nome)

    perfil = Usuario.objects.create(
        usuario=id_usuario,
        cpf=cpf,
        celular=celular
    )

    user.save()
    perfil.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        nome = User.objects.filter(email=email).values_list('username', flat=True).get()
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=nome, password=senha)

        # Login pos cadastro
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)

    return redirect('home')


else:
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html')
```

cadastro.html

```
<div class="row mx-md-n5">
                            <div class="col-11">
                                <div class="contact-form-area">
                                    <form action="{% url 'cadastro' %}" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-11 col-lg-11">
                                                <label for="nome"><b>Nome completo</b></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome"
                                                       placeholder="Ex.:Andre Geraseev"
                                                       required maxlength="40">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-11 col-lg-11">
                                                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                                       placeholder="Ex.: ageraseev@gmail.com"
                                                       required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-11 col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="cpf"><b>cpf</b></label>
                                                <input minlength="14"
                                                       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Seu CPF precisa ter 11 numeros')"
                                                       oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" type="text"
                                                       data-mask="000.000.000-00"
                                                       class="form-control" name="cpf" placeholder="Digite seu CPF"
                                                       required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-11 col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="celular"><b>celular</b></label>
                                                <input type="text" data-mask="(00)0000-00000" class="form-control"
                                                       name="celular"
                                                       placeholder="Digite seu celular" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-11 col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="password"><b>Senha</b></label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                                       placeholder="Digite sua senha"
                                                       required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-11 col-lg-6">
                                                <label for="password2"><b>Confirmação de senha</b></label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2"
                                                       placeholder="Digite sua senha mais uma vez" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-11 text-center">
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger mt-4" type="submit">Criar sua conta
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqui pessoal

adicionei um dicionario (esta escrito form mas podia ser outro nome) form com o request e devolvendo ele para pagina em caso de nao passar na validação.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    nome = request.POST['nome']
    email = request.POST['email']
    senha = request.POST['password']
    senha2 = request.POST['password2']
    cpf = request.POST['cpf']
    celular = request.POST['celular']

    form= {
        "form": request.POST, }



    if campo_vazio(nome):
        messages.error(request, 'O campo nome não pode ficar em branco')
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if not validacpf(cpf):
        messages.error(request, 'CPF invalido', "cpf")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if campo_vazio(email):
        messages.error(request, 'O campo email não pode ficar em branco', "email")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if campo_vazio(cpf):
        messages.error(request, 'O campo CPF não pode ficar em branco', "cpf")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if campo_vazio(celular):
        messages.error(request, 'O campo celular não pode ficar em branco', "celular")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if senhas_nao_sao_iguais(senha, senha2):
        messages.error(request, 'As senhas não são iguais', "senha2")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'Email já cadastrado', "email")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if Usuario.objects.filter(cpf=cpf).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'CPF ja cadastrado', "cpf")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
    if User.objects.filter(username=nome).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'Usuário já cadastrado', "nome")
        return render(request, 'cadastro.html', form)
```

cadastro.html

```
<label for="nome"><b>Nome completo</b></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome"
                                                   placeholder="Ex.:Andre Geraseev"
                                                   required maxlength="40" value="{{ form.nome }}" >
```